# Rotate shape netlogo

Tags: netlogo, shapes

I create several turtles with the same shape. One of them I need to rotate 90 degrees.I tried `rt` and also `heading`. Nothing works. When I created the shape I cancelled the rotation - does it influence. How ca n I set may shape rotated. All these shapes  doesn`t move.

```
crt 0 [
      setxy 0  / 4) 0
      set shape "tunnel"
      set heading 200
      set size 10]

crt 1 [
      setxy 10 0
      set shape "tunnel"
      set heading 200
      set size 10]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some NetLogo turtle shapes are by default not rotatable.
When you open the "Turtle Shapes Editor" (Tools Menu) you will see that some shapes are framed within a circle (rotatable), whereas others are framed within a box (not rotatable). However, you can easily change this setting for the default shapes and also for your own shapes. Just edit a non-rotatable shape and check the `rotatable` checkbox in the lower left.

Comment: If I edit rotatable to be true, each time I add the shape it has different position. It should be vertical or horizontal only. For that reason I cancelled rotatable  and set The shape to be vertical. I wanted to rotate it only once to have horizontal position

Comment: Thats because it represents the current heading of the turtle. The heading of newly created turtles is random by default. You have to set the heading when you create the turtle if you want the shape to point in a specific direction (e.g. set heading 0, if you want to point the shape upwards, set heading 90 if you want to point the shape to the horizontal right)